# development magento form for frontend

Tags: magento

I am developing an extension for magento. I want to add a form in frontend to add "title" and "description". I searched a lot but failed to find good magento module development tutorial
Someone please guide me how to add form and its validation for magento

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See below your it is very help full to you.

**Custom Module with Custom Database Table**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

**Front-End Editor Extension for Magento Commerce**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALgdsMCVuH4

please see above the URL and let me know if not working.

Comment: Thanks Abid, i  have already  read this tutorial, i just want the steps to develop form for front end. so if you give me idea to develop frontend for that will be very helpful for me